# Text content did not match. Warning in React 16

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I trying to build ReactJs application with server side rendering
My entry points for client and server:

**[client.jsx](https://pastebin.com/8yHM5RBL)**

```
const store = createStore(window.__INITIAL_STATE__);

hydrate(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>{renderRoutes(routes)}</BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

**[server.jsx](https://pastebin.com/JAZ7RuAL)**

```
const app = express();

if (isDev) {
  const webpack = require('webpack');
  const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
  const config = require('../../webpack.config.js');
  const compiler = webpack(config);

  app.use(express.static('/public'));
  app.use(
    webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
      publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
      stats: 'errors-only',
    })
  );
}

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
  const htmlAttrs = helmet.htmlAttributes.toComponent();
  const bodyAttrs = helmet.bodyAttributes.toComponent();

  const context = {};
  const data = {};

  res.set('content-type', 'text/html');

  res.send(
    '<!DOCTYPE html>' +
      renderToString(
        <html {...htmlAttrs}>
          <head>
            {helmet.title.toComponent()}
            {helmet.meta.toComponent()}
            {helmet.link.toComponent()}
          </head>
          <body {...bodyAttrs}>
            <div id="root">
              <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
                {renderRoutes(routes)}
              </StaticRouter>
            </div>
            <script
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: `window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(data)}`,
              }}
            />
            <script src="/public/vendor.js" />
            <script src="/public/app.js" />
          </body>
        </html>
      )
  );
});
```

And component:

**home.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>home</div>;
  }
}

export default Home;
```

When I change in my component `Home` and refresh browser page I get this error:

> Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "home" Client: "home1"

Its ok because server render old version of my code. How to reload the code on the server so that the client and server versions are equal?

Comment: i'm getting a very similar error - using staticRouter in server and browserRouter in client. i've got a bunch of routes and when i visit one of these routes directly (i.e. not via client side routing) it works but getting the JS error.

Comment: this article could help out: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-server-rendering/
There is a section with your same error - just find 'Text content did not match' on the page to view.

Answer (score 33):

For those discovering this error because your client and server purposefully render different content (like the server rendering a dark theme which gets replaced with the user preference on load), use `suppressHydrationWarning` to suppress the error.

For example:

```
<div suppressHydrationWarning>Ignore this</div>
```

Comment: thanks this help me, it was very simple =D, Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that your server-side application does not reflect code changes. To do that you have to configure your express app as a webpack entry.

Briefly, you need 2 webpack configurations one for server and another for client code.
The server one will look something like this

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    server: './server.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  target: 'node',
  node: {
    // Need this when working with express, otherwise the build fails
    __dirname: false,   // if you don't put this is, __dirname
    __filename: false,  // and __filename return blank or /
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()], // Need this to avoid error when working with Express
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        // Transpiles ES6-8 into ES5
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        // Loads the javacript into html template provided.
        // Entry point is set below in HtmlWebPackPlugin in Plugins 
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [{loader: "html-loader"}]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./index.html",
      filename: "./index.html",
      excludeChunks: [ 'server' ]
    })
  ]
}
```

Here is a [nice article](https://medium.com/@binyamin/creating-a-node-express-webpack-app-with-dev-and-prod-builds-a4962ce51334) explaining how to do that in details

Answer (score 1):

No one said about but Cloudflare replaced double spaces with a space when you enable Auto Minify (HTML) in optimization.
And this error will happen.